# RuntimeError: b'Unable to find user for dataApp registration. Please, login.' oon Shapelets-Platform

Tags: python, text, visualization, collaboration

I have been using Shapelets platform for a while and something weird happened recently. I was working on a project for a couple of weeks (No problem running the Data app), and the following day I had this type of error and could not register my apps anymore.
RuntimeError: b'Unable to find user for dataApp registration. Please, login.'
did it happen to anyone? I tried with the GitHub examples and it is the same "